# AdMob 6.0 + Android 2.3, it´s possible?

Tags: android, version, admob

I created a project with version 3.2 of android and set the AdMob, but many people can not download the game because it´s in a new version. I could see that, there are many people using Android 2.2 and 2.3, and then can not download, it´s possible make work AdMob 6.0 with android version 2.2 or 2.3? Can some one help me?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Admob 6.0 README.txt file states that it requires Android 1.5 or later.  Why would you think that it wouldn't work with version 2.3?

Have you actually tried using an Android SDK target version of 2.3?

Comment: Well, in this site [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals), say it´s compiling against at least Android v3.2.

Comment: Hum, How I can change the SDK version to 1.5 or 2.2 at least, and compile for 3.2? Who has a mobile with Android 2.2 version, will have access to download it and play? Can you help me?

Comment: I changed to version 2.2 and I got an error saying "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges." . I have this, but when I change the SDK to 3.2, it´s works fine.

Comment: I believe you need the following in your Manifest.xml file: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/> And set your Eclipse to target Android 3.2.

Comment: Here's a good starting point to learn how to support older versions of Android: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html